# Why I get only one element in slot inside v-for?

Tags: javascript, vue.js

In my vue application code, I have a swiper component. inside this component I have a v-for and a slot.

In the parent component (Foo) I need to catch the component (baz) I put into slot, by ref. the problem is its return **only one element** not array as I though so.

How to keep this shape of components and still get the array I expected? is it possible?

```js
import Vue from "vue";

Vue.config.productionTip = false;

const Foo = {
  template: `
    <div>
    <swiper :items="items">
    <baz ref="baz"/>
    </swiper>
    </div>
  `,
  data: function() {
    return {
      items: [1, 2, 3, 4, 5]
    };
  },
  mounted: function() {
    this.$nextTick().then(() => {
      console.log({ refs: this.$refs.baz });
    });
  }
};

const Baz = { template: "<div>im baz</div>" };

const Swiper = {
  template: `
    <div class="swiper">
    <div v-for="(item, i) in items" :key="i">
        <slot></slot>
    </div>
    </div>
    `,
  props: ["items"]
};


Vue.component("foo", Foo);
Vue.component("baz", Baz);
Vue.component("swiper", Swiper);

new Vue({
  render: h => h(Foo)
}).$mount("#app");
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/vue/2.6.11/vue.js"></script>
```

Answer (score 1):

You need to change your structure. Instead of using `v-for` in `swiper` template, use it in `foo` template. Let `swiper` template handle rendering only a single item. Here's a working example of what you expected: https://codesandbox.io/s/jolly-meninsky-qqe6k